# Java handler error

Tags: java, error-handling, handler

I am getting errors and i don't know why.

```
//skip 26-48
public void skip1() {
    session.setAttribute("baseline_du_26_years","-9");
    session.setAttribute("baseline_du_26_0","-9");
}
```

Here is where its being called

```
else if (session.getAttribute("baseline_du_25_1").equals("1")) {
    skip1();
    to="baseline_du_49.jsp";
```

I get back these

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
```

Also on the call of the function I get these

```
The method skip1() is undefined for the type handler_jsp
```

What is wrong with this?

This is the primary issue

```
public void skip1() {
```

EDIT ~~~~~
this worked

```
public void skip1(HttpSession session){
// code here
}


skip1(session);
```

Comment: Please show more context. You've probably put the method in the wrong place (e.g. in the middle of another method) or something similar.

Comment: I have tryed palcing it in multuple locations, all with the same error. It has to deal with the "public void skip1()"

Comment: Well if you're not going to give us any more information, I'm afraid we can't help you.

Comment: Im not sure what to add, I dont know what the issue is so I dont know what area to post, the whole thing is over 3000 lines.

Comment: Well cut it down so that it's *not* 3000 lines. Reduce it to a bare minimum example which shows the same problem. That's part of the diagnostic process. You may well find the problem while you cut it down.

Comment: I will try, my boss will give me a helping hand here shortly too, he pushes me to do coding that is over my head. ill return here later in the day. Sorry to suck at explaining my problem.

Comment: this is what worked out   skip1(session); and                          public void skip3(HttpSession session){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as this error is concern

> The method skip1() is undefined for the type handler_jsp

It seems you have not defined `skip1()` in your JSP. You can declare using scriptlet.

```
<% !
 public void skip1(HttpSession session) {
       session.setAttribute("baseline_du_26_years","-9");
       session.setAttribute("baseline_du_26_0","-9");
}
%>
```

Make sure you have the `session` variable passed to the method `skip1()`.

Comment: Adding that gave me a mass of more errors, but then again I didnt pass the session variable, (don't know what that means >< )

Comment: Very close to what I needed, thank you!